# Android Manifest ActiviyNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

I am working on a university project and have an app with 50+ activities. Some of the app already existed and I added to it.
Some of the pages had too much content to fit small devices so I locked it to large screens. When I added the code to limit the screen sizes,  was getting an error of duplicate activites in my manifest. When I had a look I saw the following repeated 3 times:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Objective"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_objective" >
        </activity>
```

However, there is only one activity in the project with this name.

After removing this, the app worked fine and it was now limited to large screen sizes. However, I have just attempted to reload it on the emulator and I am getting the following error:

```
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ucl.pga/com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Observation}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I understand this is saying the activity does not exist, but I am sure it does. I am also sure this is something to do with the 3 instances I removed.

The activity I am trying to load is:

```
com.ucl.pga.db.Objective
```

The full manifest is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ucl.pga"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.AppointmentListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_appointment_list"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.ucl.pga.LoginActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.AppointmentDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_apointment_details"
            android:parentActivityName="com.ucl.pga.AppointmentListActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.ucl.pga.AppointmentListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.ActivityMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.sync.AuthenticatorActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >

            <!--
                No intent-filter here! This activity is only ever launched by
                someone who explicitly knows the class name

            -->
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.sync.AuthenticationService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.sync.SyncService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.sync.Provider"
            android:authorities="com.ucl.pga.sync.Provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:multiprocess="true" >
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.Assessment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_assessment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Objective"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_objective" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Subjective"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_subjective" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.Objective.Observation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_observation" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Joint_Integrity_Tests"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_joint__integrity__tests" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Active_Movements"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activee__movements" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Passive_Movements"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_passive__movements" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Repeated_Movements"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_repeated__movements" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Combined_Movements"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_combined__movements" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Capsular_Pattern"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_capsular__pattern" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Joint_Effusion"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_joint__effusion" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.PPIVMs"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ppivms" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Other_Joints_Involved"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_other__joints__involved" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Muscle_Strength"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_muscle__strength" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Muscle_Control"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_muscle__control" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Muscle_Length"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_muscle__length" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Isometric_Muscle_Tests"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_isometric__muscle__tests" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Integrity_Of_Nervous_System"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_integrity__of__nervous__system" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Mobility_Of_Nervous_System"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mobility__of__nervous__system" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Diagnostic_Tests"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_diagnostic__tests" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Special_Tests"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_special__tests" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Accessory_Movements"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_accessory__movements" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Palpation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_palpatation" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Conclusion"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_conclusion" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Diagnosis"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_diagnosis" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Consent"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_consent" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Onset"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_onset" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Symptoms"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_symptoms" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Location"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_location" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Depth"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_depth" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Nature"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nature" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Agg"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_agg" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Ease"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ease" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Twentfour_Hours"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_twentfour__hours" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Sin_Factor"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sin__factor" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Pain_Score"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pain__score" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Status"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_status" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.History"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_history" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Past_Medical_History"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_past__medical__history" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Drug_History"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drug__history" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Other_Comments"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_other__comments" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Special_Questions"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_special__questions" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Summary"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_summary" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Subjective.Summary1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_summary1" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the full logcat is below:

```
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     ... 11 more
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ucl.pga/com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Observation}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     at com.ucl.pga.Assessment.onClick(Assessment.java:102)
08-18 09:34:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1729):     ... 14 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: spelling mistakes errors please look carefully

Answer (score 0):

From the logcat error:

```
com.ucl.pga/com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Observation
```

which is different from the manifest

```
android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Objective"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
just change this 

<activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Objective"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_objective" >
        </activity>


to 

<activity
            android:name="com.ucl.pga.db.Objective. Observation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_objective" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your class name in Manifest.xml is wrong, you're using `com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Objective` and error look for `com.ucl.pga.db.Objective.Observation`

if your class name is wrong change it and test again